# Django Database: design of a model that combines two models

Tags: django, database, django-models

I've got a quick question about database design and I'd love your help!

The situation is as follows. I've got two models, one for orders and one for a list of steps that this order goes through:

- Model: Orders

  - Field: Order_ID
- Model: Steps

  - Field: Step_ID
  - Field: Step_Name

But what I want is each order to have a table with a field for the order as well as for each step, in which I can put the status of that step for the order, for example:

Order ID | Step(id=1) | Step(id=2) | Step(id=3), etc.

So that for each order that's added, a step can be marked as for example [completed, delayed, skipped]:

20150401 | Completed | Delayed | Completed

But I can't seem to figure out what kind of setup in Django I need to do this. I've looked into many-to-many fields, but I need a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking fore exactly is to have extra fields to the steps based on the order using it.

If I understood your questions correctly, this called [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) We can define `Order` can have Many of `Step` and `Step` can have many of `Order` so this is a `ManytoMany` relationship. However, you need extra data for that relationship, and thats why you need to use `through` keyword in the relationship in order to link an instance to that relationship.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField(...)


class Step(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order, through='StepOrder')


class StepOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step)

    ## date of the order starting this step
    date_created = models.DateField(...)
    date_end = models.DateField(...)

    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="Pending")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new model called OrderStep which combines the two.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...


class Step(models.Model):
    step_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order, through='OrderStep')


class OrderStep(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Thank you, Alistair! I'm sorry, I've made Othman's answer the accepted one, because I had to choose someone! I really appreciate your help!